# How do I check the value on selected option on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to check the value in the selected on page load. If the value is `Yes` the `tab` should be show by default and if `n/a`, will be hide. After page load, user can change the option to `yes` or `n/a` and it will show/hide onchange. I'm able to do the onchange but not for the first time load.

```
<div class="form-group ">
    <select name="PrivateTeam" id="PrivateTeam" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">-- Select Option --</option>
        <option value="n/a" 
            <?php echo set_select('PrivateTeam', 'n/a', ('n/a' == $team->PrivateTeam) ? TRUE : FALSE); ?>>n/a
        </option>
        <option value="Yes" 
            <?php echo set_select('PrivateTeam', 'Yes', ('Yes' == $team->PrivateTeam) ? TRUE : FALSE); ?>>Yes
        </option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab_Task" data-toggle="tab">Task</a></li>
        <li id="li_PrivReq"><a href="#tab_PrivReq" data-toggle="tab">Private Team Requesters</a></li>
        <li id="li_AltApp"><a href="#tab_AltApp" data-toggle="tab">Alternative Approver</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_Task">
            <?php $this->load->view('team/team/edit/_Task'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_PrivReq">
            <?php $this->load->view('team/team/edit/_PrivRequester'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_AltApp">
            <?php $this->load->view('team/team/edit/_AltApprover'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#PrivateTeam").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val === "Yes") {
            $("#li_PrivReq").show();
            $("#tab_PrivReq").show();
        } else {
            $("#li_PrivReq").hide();
            $("#tab_PrivReq").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just trigger on change seperate from declaration like below

```
$("#PrivateTeam").trigger('change');
```

so code will become something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#PrivateTeam").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val === "Yes") {
            $("#li_PrivReq").show();
            $("#tab_PrivReq").show();
        } else {
            $("#li_PrivReq").hide();
            $("#tab_PrivReq").hide();
        }
    });
   $("#PrivateTeam").trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

create a function for check value **hide_show(select_val)** and pass select field value in that function.call function at the page load time and on select box change time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var privateTeam = $('#PrivateTeam').val();
  hide_show(privateTeam);
  
  $("#PrivateTeam").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        hide_show(val);
  });
});

function hide_show(privateTeam){
 if (privateTeam === "Yes") {
       $("#li_PrivReq").show();
       $("#tab_PrivReq").show();
   } else {
       $("#li_PrivReq").hide();
       $("#tab_PrivReq").hide();
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group ">
    <select name="PrivateTeam" id="PrivateTeam" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">-- Select Option --</option>
        <option value="n/a">n/a
        </option>
        <option value="Yes" selected>Yes
        </option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab_Task" data-toggle="tab">Task</a></li>
        <li id="li_PrivReq"><a href="#tab_PrivReq" data-toggle="tab">Private Team Requesters</a></li>
        <li id="li_AltApp"><a href="#tab_AltApp" data-toggle="tab">Alternative Approver</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_Task">
           tab Task
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_PrivReq">
            tab PrivReq
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_AltApp">
            tab AltApp
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```